# converting this unknown data (perhaps hex) to actual numbers in action script 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, arrays, hex

I get this out put (each row is a different element) and I don't know how to convert it in to a readable value.

R®

R®

,r

ë

äL

Â:

it should be number with 9-10 digits. from what I have seen in other sites regarding this specific data (this is the value of the tempo in a midi file) - it looks something like this: "tempo is 06 96 27 (in hexa format)"

these values are ByteArray type. how do I convert them to the readable numbers (or perhaps they contain text)?

Answer (score 1):

Try `ByteArray.readFloat()/readInt()/readDouble()` depending on what each number is meant to be

Comment: I tried doing ByteArray.readFloat(R®) / ByteArray.readInt(R®) / ByteArray.readDouble(R®) and it gets me this error: "Call to a possibly undefined method readInt through a reference with static type Class.". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the methods aren't static. If your ByteArray is called "myByteArray", then get the number like "var num:Number = myByteArray.readNumber()"

Comment: Check our the docs for more info: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#readDouble()